# Change array list to list of lists java

Tags: java, arraylist

I have two lists and I want to make a list of lists.  For some reason after I print out each list, I get a massive one entry in the array.  I am using the data coming from a hash map, and need to split the key string to get the values back, then cast the integer to a string to add to array.

```
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> listOLists = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
    ArrayList<String> singleList = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (Entry<String, Integer> entry : counts.entrySet()) {
              String val = entry.getValue().toString();               
              List<String> key = Arrays.asList(entry.getKey().split("@"));
              singleList.add(key.get(0));
              singleList.add(key.get(1));
              singleList.add(key.get(2));
              singleList.add(val);
              listOLists.add(singleList);
        }


        for(ArrayList<String> s: listOLists){
            System.out.println(s);
        }
```

I am getting:

```
[Demo-Site, 172.20.58.160, 2015-08-06, 12, Demo-Site, 10.227.145.103, 2015-08-19, 1, Demo-Site, 10.7.0.146, 2015-08-11, 3,
```

I want in the final output to look something like this:

```
[[Demo-site, 172.20.58.160, 2015-08-06, 12], [Demo-site, 10.227.145.103, 2015-08-19, 1]..etc]
```

Comment: Show what you are getting and how you are printing

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ updated post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you add in the same single list in every iteration.
Just put singleList = new ArrayList(); in tle loop body.

Answer (score 1):

Have the last println as
sopln ("[" + s + "]");
something like this should give you the output that you want.